# Date plus one month php

Tags: php, date

I have a small problem with dates in PHP.

When I made 31 + 1 month of January 
with this code

```
$newDate = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('31-01-2016'.' + 1 month'));
echo $newDate;
```

it gives me 2 March but I need given me 29 February,

I need to add 1 month and is not 30days.

ditto for all dates:
for example
01 january + 1 month => 1 february

29 january + 1 month => 29 february

30 january + 1 month => 29 february

31 january + 1 month => 29 february

Thank for your help

Comment: 29 of february is less than one month after 30 of january. I don't see the problem.

Comment: I hope there is no direct function in php to achieve it...

Comment: https://eval.in/610030

Comment: @apokryfos february is 1 month, 28 days or 29 days in leap years.

Comment: @Max by this logic 05-Jan + 1 month should be 03-Feb. It's January is 31 days though so it isn't.

Comment: Yes, and the diffent approach to both scenarios (a month being 30 days or the actual length of the month) is also pointed out in the comments of the duplicate question I referred to.

Comment: @Max I missed that bit. You're right

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think you are looking for this type of dates.

```
<?php
    $date = date('2016-01-31');
    $currentMonth = date("m",strtotime($date));
    $nextMonth = date("m",strtotime($date."+1 month"));
    if($currentMonth==$nextMonth-1 && (date("j",strtotime($date)) != date("t",strtotime($date)))){
        $nextDate = date('Y-m-d',strtotime($date." +1 month"));
    }else{
        $nextDate = date('Y-m-d', strtotime("last day of next month",strtotime($date)));
    }
    echo "Next date would be : $nextDate";
?>
```

Check live demo : https://eval.in/610034

1. If date is `31-01-2016` then next date would be `29-02-2016`
2. If date is `25-01-2016` then next date would be `25-02-2016`

Answer (score 2):

Simply try:

```
$date = new DateTime('2016-01-31');
$date->modify('last day of next month');
```

This of course only counts if you always go from the end of one moth to the end of the next one.

Comment: I'd personally first do a `+1 month` and check if the new month is not `(previous+1)%12` and then do this.

Comment: @apokryfos you're right. It would be best then to use `next month`, wouldn't it?

Comment: I don't think there's a single calculation to get OPs desired result because it is such a non-standard thing to do.

Comment: @apokryfos In C# there are methods `addDays, addMonths, addYears` build in the Framework. It's not 'such a non-standard thing'. The idea of 'next month' is VERY standard. My boss wants it, our customers want it. That's why I'm here.

Comment: @Bitterblue getting 29 of February by adding 1 month to 31 of January is what it not standard here.

Comment: @apokryfos Well, ask you granma what should happen. Or better ask someone from the accounts department. Or even far more better, ask a solid and very successful framework just to have a more consistent software development throughout the world. .NET goes to 29. Fab. I just checked.

Comment: @Bitterblue well, PHP doesn't do this. JavaScript's Date doesn't do this either, Java's Calendar has two methods, `add` and `roll` with `roll` doing this while `add` returning March. Where I'm standing it doesn't seem standard.

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
$date = "2016-01-29";
$date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime("last day of next month",strtotime($date)));
echo $date;
```

https://3v4l.org/Y9PpV

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this:

```
date_default_timezone_set('UTC');

$current_month = (int) date('m');
$year = date('y');
$newDate = date('Y-m-d', strtotime('31-1-2016'.' + 1 month'));

if($current_month == 12) 
{
    $new_month=0;
    $year++;
}

$d = new DateTime( $year.'-'.($current_month+1).'-01' ); 
echo $d->format( 'Y-m-t' )."\n";
```

Change $current_month / $year based on your needs......